# PHP difficulties connecting MyAdmin MySQL database to site hosted by DreamHost

Tags: php, mysql, dreamhost

I am having difficulty with the code I have written, as it does not connect by SQL database to my site.

I have recently made a website on dreamweaver, and it is now public and hosted by DreamHost.

I have also logged into the 'MySQL database management of Dreamhost' and created a database with multiple tables.

I have since created a PHP script to connect the database to my site and have uploaded it to the site. The following is an example of the script:

"

```
   $db_host="andrewsmith.com"; 
   $db_username="andrews"; 
   $db_pass="*******";
   $db_name="database345";

   @mysql_connect("$db_host", "db_username", "$db_pass") or die ("Could not connect to 
   MySQL"); 

   @mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("No database");

   echo ("Successful connection");
```

?>
"

However, my issue is the page always shows the message "Could not connect to MySQL". This is likely a coding problem, I just can't see where I have gone wrong. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks for considering this question

James

Comment: either the host or the user-name ore the password is wrong. i suspect host should be **localhost**

Comment: put $db_host="andrewsmith.com";  as $db_host="localhost";

Comment: I am not using WAMP or XAMP, does that matter?

Comment: It still comes up with 'Could not connect to MySQL'

Comment: are you tried to connect to that mysql server from outside your host?

Comment: the username and password are specific to the database

Comment: Yes I am trying to connect to the mysql server from outside the host, and it has always failed

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions so far

Comment: ok, you need to allow your `IP` or `HOST` to be allowed in that MySQL server, otherwise, you can't connect to it, in Cpanel, there is an option for doing that, but I tried to use it, its not working for me, I hope it works on DreamHost

Comment: full details at the start would of helped ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A dreamhost database uses a subdomain to point to the actual mysql instance. There-for the fix will be adding mysql.domainname.com. You can find the correct database hostname in dreamhosts cpanel under databases.